# how to listen for buy events of specific token?

Tags: web3js, web3.py, pancakeswap

I was just trying to create something which will listen to buy(pancakeswap, poopcoin) events of a specific smart contract.

As for me, I am stopped at a certain point. The code below is a contract of WBNB I was just testing code with it

```
token_CA = "0xbb4CdB9CBd36B01bD1cBaEBF2De08d9173bc095c"
token_abi = utils.getTokenAbi(token_CA)

contract = web3.eth.contract(address=web3.toChecksumAddress(token_CA), abi=token_abi)
```

And For the listening Mechanism, I have Following Code

```
def handle_event(event):
    result = Web3.toJSON(event)
    contractI = json.loads(result)['args']['dst']
    txn_hash = json.loads(result)['transactionHash']
    # print(txn_hash)
    if contractI.lower() == "0x10ed43c718714eb63d5aa57b78b54704e256024e".lower():
        receipt = json.loads(web3.toJSON(web3.eth.get_transaction(txn_hash)))
        value = receipt['value']
        print(f'value is {value} BNB', end='\n')
        print(receipt)

async def log_loop(event_filter, poll_interval):
    while True:
        for event in event_filter.get_new_entries():
            handle_event(event)
            await asyncio.sleep(poll_interval)

def main():
    event_filter = contract.events.Transfer.createFilter(fromBlock='latest')
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    try:
        loop.run_until_complete(
            asyncio.gather(
                log_loop(event_filter, 2)
            )
        )
    finally:
        loop.close()
```

Well, This Code Just Listen To Transfer Events Of WBNB & I am trying to Get Pancakeswap Events By Matching Destination Address To Pancakeswap Router Contract Address.

At this point I am confused about how the heck I get buy event of the specific token, anyone has an idea or something share it with your junior, please.